# WebdriverIo + TypeScript: How to generate stack trace for ts files

Tags: typescript, automation, webdriver, stack-trace, webdriver-io

When I run my test by running `./wdio.conf.js` and the test fails somewhere I am getting stack trace path like: `C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\BackUp\Project\ts-built\tests\first_test.js`.

It navigates me to the JS file and doesn't show the row number, where the test failed. I tried to add source-map-support, but it works only when I run my test via Mocha, but Mocha doesn't start web driver.

Is there some solution to have a stack trace that points to the problem in the TS files?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also looking to get source location and source maps working in my wdio tests